# Why the li hover is covering only the text part and not the whole li box?

Tags: html, css, hover, css-grid

I'm trying to give the hover effect to the `li` which appears to cover only the text part and not the whole `li-box`. I wonder why is it happening like this?

```css
*{
box-sizing: border-box;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
html, body{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

.container {
display: grid;
background-color: rosybrown;
border: 1px solid black;
justify-items: center;
}
.heading{
order: 2;
}

.main-nav{
order:1;
text-align: center;
width: 100%;
border-bottom: 1px solid rebeccapurple;
padding: .5em;
}

.main-nav ul{
 margin:0;
 }
.main-nav li:hover{
background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
}

 ul{
 padding: 0;
 }
 .main-nav li{
 display: inline;
 margin: 1em;
    
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Document</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="trialStyle.css">
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="container">
    <h1 class="heading">The Love</h1>
    <nav class="main-nav">
        <ul class="ulContainer">
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>About</li>
        <li>Store</li>
    </ul>
    </nav>
 </div>
</body>
   </html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The hover effect only covers the text part because that is the size of the rendered `li` element.
If you want the effect over a block, you could use `padding` instead of `margin` CSS property:

*Refer the given link of W3 Schools below*

```css
*{
box-sizing: border-box;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

html, body{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

.container {
display: grid;
background-color: rosybrown;
border: 1px solid black;
justify-items: center;
}

.heading{
order: 2;
}

.main-nav{
order:1;
text-align: center;
width: 100%;
border-bottom: 1px solid rebeccapurple;
padding: .5em;
}

.main-nav ul{
 margin:0;
 }

.main-nav li:hover{
background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
}

 ul{
 padding: 0;
 }

 .main-nav li{
 display: inline;
 /*padding: 1em;
 padding-bottom: 0.5em;*/
 padding: .5em;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Document</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="trialStyle.css">
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="container">
    <h1 class="heading">The Love</h1>
    <nav class="main-nav">
        <ul class="ulContainer">
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>About</li>
        <li>Store</li>
    </ul>
    </nav>
 </div>
</body>
   </html>
```

[CSS Box Model](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp)

Answer (score 1):

You can add padding to give space around text and display hover on it.

```css
 .main-nav li{
 display: inline;
 margin: 1em;
 padding: 1em;

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am interpreting it right you are trying to get the li element to cover the entire height of the bar. If so the problem would be that you need to set the height of the li element to 100%. So edit your css script to look something like this:

```
.main-nav li{
display: inline;
margin: 1em;
height:100%;
}
```

*Basically the text is the entire element because no dimensions are set so you have to set them like this.

Comment: Thanks buddy for your valuable effort but it doesn't seem to work